# How can I reset all the row of numbering into all 1 if the date was ended

Tags: r

How can reset the row of numbering into 1 when the date was ended

````
```r
Code <- c('01BL', '01BP', '02BP', '03BP', '04BP')
Numbering <- c(4,6,10,34,3)
dfdate <- format.Date(Sys.Date(),"%m")


df <- data.frame(Code = Code, Numbering = Numbering, Date = dfdate)

df$Numbering <- ifelse(df$Date != format.Date(Sys.Date(),"%m"), 1, df$Numbering)

df
````

````
This is the output that i have:
```r

     Code Numbering   Date
    1 01BL         4   08
    2 01BP         6   08
    3 02BP        10   08
    4 03BP        34   08
    5 04BP         3   08
````

if the number was change in the column date after the month was ended 
 this is the output that I want:

```r
     Code   Numbering  Date
    1 01BL         1   09
    2 01BP         1   09
    3 02BP         1   09
    4 03BP         1   09
    5 04BP         1   09
```

Comment: here the output that i want

Comment: Code     Numbering
1 01BL         1
2 01BP         1
3 02BP         1
4 03BP         1
5 04BP         1

Comment: Please edit the output you want into the question, instead of burying it in a comment.

Comment: How do you define `date was ended` ?

Comment: by getting the date from my computer also..if the date was change the it will reset

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want `Numbering` to be 1 if the `Date` is less than your machine's date -

```
df$Numbering <- ifelse(df$Date < Sys.Date(), 1, df$Numbering)
```

For the updated question -

```
df$Numbering <- with(df, 
  ifelse(format.Date(Date,"%m") != format.Date(Sys.Date(),"%m"), 1, Numbering)
)
```